# How do I cluster in the following dataset for source IP address by records

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

[The question asks one to cluster the source IP address by the number of records they appear in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc0dW.png)

How do I cluster the IP addresses by the number of records they appear in?
I have tried running this-

```
 DIP_count  = df['destIP'].value_counts()
 kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
 kmeans.fit(DIP_count)
```

The output comes off like-
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q4L4.png)

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1.3505e+04 2.2600e+02 2.2400e+02 2.1500e+02 2.1500e+02 2.1400e+02
 2.1400e+02 2.1200e+02 2.1100e+02 2.1000e+02 2.0900e+02 2.0800e+02
 2.0500e+02 2.0400e+02 2.0400e+02 2.0200e+02 2.0000e+02 1.9900e+02
 1.9500e+02 1.8700e+02 7.4000e+01 6.3000e+01 3.1000e+01 2.4000e+01
```

With the final statement being-

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and the *specific* issue(s) encountered; see how to create a [MCVE]. SO is not a code writing service - we are more than happy to assist resolving issues with your code, but we cannot write your code for you.

Comment: @desertnaut have made the changes please have a look, quite new to the platform,sorry

Comment: Please post the full error trace (where exactly does the error pop up?), and remove all code that is irrelevant to the issue (plots, prints etc)

Comment: @desertnaut have added the error trace in the image and done as you asked. Once again apologies for not being clear with the question.

Comment: Kudos for being responsive to advice; for the next time, please see why [an image of your exception isn't helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). What is the `array` yoou have posted? Doesn't seem to come from your code.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the advice in the error message?

Comment: @desertnaut the array comes of the value error, have not written any code for array.
Massive thanks for being so patient, really really appreciate it.

Comment: That;s one more reason why you should copy & paste *all* the trace here as text. Anyway, the first advice offered `array.reshape(-1, 1)` should do the job, as it seems you have only one feature indeed.

Comment: You are welcome, but please be advised that in your *second* question I will be harsh & w/o any patience at all if you happen to not have gone through the help system before asking.

Comment: @desertnaut thanks a ton, will definitely keep this is mind when I ask my second question. Look forward to interacting with you given your experience!